# Meaning of negative bounds coordinates in a java.awt.Shape created using Arc2D

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I draw a java.awt.Shape on a Graphics context and display it to the user. To position and size the graphics context I use the shape's bounds in a library that I created.  This works well for most of the shapes I generate.

The problem is that my positioning algorithm does not work for shapes generated using Arc2D.Float. When using this class to generate the shape I get a shape with a negative y-coordinate in its bounds.

I researched a lot but could not find any information on the meaning of this negative y-coordinate.  I can properly position this particular shape if I ignore the coordinate, but the following questions remain:

- What does the negative y-coordinate mean and how should it be handled in general?
- How does the negative coordinate relate to the bound's height?

Below is a piece of source code that demonstrates the issue.  The unmodified code that tries to translate using the shape's y-coordinate generates the following display:
[image: Bad positioning, using negative y-bounds information, note the gap at the top of the image display]
If commenting in the g.translate() line in the source code using a zero y translation, the following is displayed:
[image: Gap shown now at the bottom, bounds information silently ignored]
It seems as if the negative y needs to be subtracted from the height of the bounds. This only emphasizes that I seem to miss some basic understanding...

The only other information I found is that this is not an issue at all when using other start and end angles for the Arc that started it all.  The start angle is 0 and the arc extent is 45 degrees, all is working perfectly. So it is also possible that this is a certain mathematical issue.

I hope somebody can give an explanation...

```
public class ShapeAnomaly
{
    public static void main( String[] argv ) throws Exception
    {
        //
        // Create the shape.
        //
        Shape shape = null;
        {
            Rectangle arcBounds = new Rectangle( 0, 0, 500, 500 );

            Path2D gp = new Path2D.Float();
            gp.append( new Arc2D.Float( arcBounds,
                        22.5f,
                        90.0f,
                        Arc2D.OPEN ), true );
            gp.closePath();

            shape = gp;
        }

        //
        // Create an image and paint the shape.
        //
        final Image image;
        {
            Rectangle2D bounds = shape.getBounds2D();
            System.err.println( "Bounds: " + bounds );

            BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(
                    (int)bounds.getWidth(),
                    (int)bounds.getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );

            Graphics2D g = bImage.createGraphics();

            if ( bounds.getY() < 0 )
                System.err.println( "Anomaly..." );

            //
            // What is the correct handling of the bounds y-coordinate when
            // drawing the shape?
            // Should work, thought I know why, but doesn't.
            g.translate( -bounds.getX(), -bounds.getY() );
            // Works, but dunno why?
            //g.translate( -bounds.getX(), 0 ); 

            g.fill( shape );
            g.dispose();
            image = bImage;
        }

        //
        // Show the image in a window.
        //
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Shape anomaly..." );
                frame.getContentPane().add( new JLabel( new ImageIcon( image ) ) );
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.pack();

                frame.setVisible( true );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for the getBounds2D() method of Path2D.Float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Float.html#getBounds2D--):

> Note that there is no guarantee that the returned `Rectangle2D` is the smallest bounding box that encloses the `Shape`, only that the `Shape` lies entirely within the indicated `Rectangle2D`.

This is actually just a copy of the [general contract of Shape.getBounds2D()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#getBounds2D--).

I don't know if there's a proper way to get the real bounds of an arbitrary Shape.  My instinct would be to use a flattened PathIterator, which is guaranteed to contain only moveTo, lineTo and close operations:

```
Rectangle2D bounds = null;
float[] coords = new float[6];
for (PathIterator i = shape.getPathIterator(null, 1);
     !i.isDone();
     i.next()) {

    if (i.currentSegment(coords) != PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE) {
        float x = coords[0];
        float y = coords[1];
        if (bounds == null) {
            bounds = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, 0, 0);
        } else {
            bounds.add(x, y);
        }
    }
}
System.err.println( "Bounds: " + bounds );
```

Comment: Great, this is the solution.  Actually I even read the cited part of the documentation many times, but since I've never seen it I started to ignore it.  Fact is:  I used the code snipped you posted and fitted it into my code and it works perfectly, i.e. it returns the actual bounds of the passed shapes in good accuracy. The solution is cool and I learnt something.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I ment I never saw it *before* and dit not realize that I see it *now*.  :^)